# Getting zero as result from MS Excel VBA Code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am very new to VBA coding and I want to make a custom function where there are multiple employees and each employee has a degree (level). The higher the level the more Salary he gets.

There are 7 degrees but in this example I made it 2 total degrees so it is easier to understand.

Now this Prime level "PLevel" is further divided into 11 Sublevels "SLevel".  In this example I made it less.

So basically if employee "Alex" is at level 1 then he starts with 1000. Then he gets and additional X based on his SLevel value.
If Alex has PLevel=1 and SLevel=2  Then he gets 1002.

Using a lot of google and youtube this is what I came up with. Problem is that the result is always ZERO.
This is what I did:

1. Open Excel and create new module, write code, save file as .xlsm file.
2. Insert a value in cell "A2" and "B2"
3. Then in cell "C2" write this `=Salary(A2,B2)`

```
Function Salary(PLevel As Double, SLevel As Double)

If PLevel = "1" Then
GoTo Line1
ElseIf PLevel = "2" Then
GoTo Line2

End If


Line1:
PLevel = "1000"

    If SLevel = 1 Then
    SalarySum = PLevel + 1
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 2 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 2
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 3 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 3
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 4 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 4
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 5 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 5
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 6 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 6
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 7 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 7
        
   GoTo LastLine
   
    End If
    

Line2:
PLevel = "2000"

    If SLevel = 1 Then
    SalarySum = PLevel + 1
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 2 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 2
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 3 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 3
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 4 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 4
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 5 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 5
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 6 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 6
        
        ElseIf SLevel = 7 Then
        SalarySum = PLevel + 7
        
   GoTo LastLine
   
    End If


LastLine:


End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return` something by having a line which states `functionName = Value`.

In your case the last line of your code before the `End Function` should be

```
Salary = SalarySum
```

Or whatever your return is.

You may also need to specify the type to be returned while declaring your function, like so:

```
Function Salary(PLevel As Double, SLevel As Double) As Integer
```

Currently your function is missing those important parts for Excel VBA to know what to return.

A better guide to the absolute minimum you need in a UDF (user defined function) is [How to Write User Defined Functions (UDFs) in Excel with VBA](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/user-defined-functions-explained/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I get the results I want.